# Ruby on Rails: faye-websocket-ruby, undefined method 'on'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, faye

I'm working to set up a server-side websocket on my Rails application and am unable to continue because I am receiving this error message

> "undefined method 'on' for #< Faye::WebSocket:0x00000007bfb808 >".

I'm using code from the actual [README](https://github.com/faye/faye-websocket-ruby/blob/master/README.md) of faye-websocket-ruby's github and the on method is not working.

This is my simple test. It receives the request and creates a `Faye::WebSocket` object successfully. But the action then crashes because it can't use the 'on' method.

```
if Faye::WebSocket.websocket?(env)
  ws = Faye::WebSocket.new(env)
  logger.debug "WE HAVE A WEBSOCKET!"

  ws.on :message do |event|
    logger.debug "WE HAVE A MESSAGE!"
  end
end
```

It is part of the API and used in numerous examples. Does anyone know why this could be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The README is outdated. I looked at ws.methods and couldn't find the on method, so I started looking through the source code. It looks like it was removed, or at least moved to websocket-driver, which would have introduced its own problems trying to integrate it. You can find the new correct syntax in one of the [examples](https://github.com/faye/faye-websocket-ruby/blob/master/examples/app.rb) though.

I replaced `ws.on :message do |event|` with `ws.onmessage = lambda do |event|` and no more crashing.